# keep sending location update from iPhone to server while the phone is in background

Tags: iphone, sockets, background, connection, multitasking

I know that it is possible to keep getting location updates while the phone is in background mode, but is it possible to keep sending this updates to my server? 
Im using NSStream to connect to the server can i still use it to send the location updates when the phone is in background?